# tar file doesn't untar completely

Tags: ubuntu, tar

I downloaded the ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar file from image-net.org. It downloaded completely i.e. 137GB. It is supposed to have about 1000 tar files inside it.
However, when I untarred the file using the following commands, I get only 372 tar files (~56GB)

```
mkdir train && mv ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar train/ && cd train
tar -xvf ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar && rm -f ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S.: I also tried untarring through 7zip (on Windows), but I get a warning: "There are some data after the end of the payload data".

Answer (score 0):

I would do a couple of things, First make sure you have the 250GB+ you need according to the link I found on github

```
df -h
```

Next if there is an MD5 hash of your file posted validate it and make sure you have everything downloaded.

```
md5sum /path/tofile/ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar
```

Next I would break your commands apart there is no reason to keep running the mkdir, cd , rm the tar file unless you want to download it multiple times.

I would do this

```
mkdir myTrainFiles
cd myTrainFiles
tar -xvf /path/tofile/ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar .
```

Also are there any specific errors your getting, maybe the file really only contains what you have already extracted?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Could you please post the link you found?

Comment: https://github.com/amd/OpenCL-caffe/wiki/Instructions-to-create-ImageNet-2012-data

Comment: Thank you!I do have sufficient space. I'm checking the checksum value now, it's taking a long time... Will let you know what happens :)

Comment: Cool, I didnt see what it was from that git link but either way follow the steps should lead you down the right path I imagine.

Comment: The checksum values don't match, however the file size is as expected... What do I do?

Comment: Redown load is about the only thing you can do

Comment: Oh :( okay... Isn't there any way to repair the file?

Comment: Not that I know of, one thing you might want to do before hand is extract with tar-xvf /path/tofile/ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar . and see what errors it give if any. If the file hash isnt matching however its unlikley you have downloaded everything correctly which might be the root cause of the entire issue.

Comment: Where is the download, and what is the MD5 hash suppose to be?

Comment: Extracting using tar -xvf ... doesn't give any errors; it simply doesn't extract the tar file completely. The tar file is supposed to have around 1000 tar files inside it, however it extracts only 372 files. The download link is the first one under the "Images" subheading in http://www.image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2012/nonpub-downloads and the MD5 hash is mentioned over there itself

Comment: I found a torrent for the file on academictorrents.com. I'm using the "checking" option of my torrent client to check if all the pieces have been downloaded correctly. Found this suggestion online :)

Comment: Cool give that a shot, I am downloading the file now from the direct link. Ill check the MD5 as well.

Comment: Okay! Thank you so much :) I guess the problem occurred because I used Free Download Manager to download the file. I have a slow internet connection, so I can't afford to download it directly; I need to keep pausing and resuming the download. :P

Comment: O that sucks, good luck I really dont have experience with download managers.

Comment: Thanks :) I hope it works! I really don't have the time or patience to redownload.

Comment: Thanks for your time! :)